# Replace accession_id in blast report with full annotation in separate file

Tags: python, replace, annotations, blast

I have a file with annotations in the following format:

```
  XS-5236245.2_hypothetical_protein
```

and a tab delimited blast report with only the accession id in the second column:

```
  transcript1  XS-5236245.2  94.3  35  0  245  356  789  896  1e-230 6.3
```

I want to replace the accession_id from the blast report with the whole line from the annotations file when there is a match. This is my attempt and as you can see I use very basic python. If you give me a more complex solution I would appreciate some explanation. Thank you for your help.

Linu

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#import sys

#input1 = sys.argv[1] --> file with annoations
#input2 = sys.argv[2] --> file with blast report
#output = sys.argv[3] --> modified blast report with annotations

f1 = open(sys.argv[1],"r")
f2 = open(sys.argv[2],"r")
f3 = open(sys.argv[3],"w")

#open and read line by line:
for line in f1:
        # break line by '_'
        splitline = line.split("_")
        # define search_id as the first element of the line
        searchid = splitline[0]
        # open blast report and read line by line
        for row in f2:
                # split columns by tab separator
                col = row.split("\t")
                # define target_id as the content of the second column
                targetid = col[1]
                # when target_id matches search_id replace content with the whole line
                if searchid == targetid:
                        f3.write(targetid.replace(searchid, splitline))
                else:
                        pass

f1.close()
f2.close()
f3.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution like so:

1. Create a new file (accessionid_headers.txt) with two columns, first column has accession ids and second column has full header. This was easy with python:

   ```
   #!usr/bin/env python
   import sys

   f1 = open(sys.argv[1],'r')
   f2 = open(sys.argv[2],'w')

   for line in f1:
       splitline = line.split('_')
       accessionid = splitline[0]
       f2.write('{0} {1}'.format(accessionid, line))

   f1.close()
   f2.close()
   ```
2. With the blast report in the following format:

   ```
   c16_g1_i1 len=581 path=[12725:0-580]    XS-5236245.2    94.9    59  3   0   403 579 254 312 8.6e-27 116.3
   ```
3. I applied the following awk that I modified to fit my files however appologies because I am not an expert in awk to fully explain each step. Maybe someone can contribute explaining what each step is doing:

   ```
   awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}$4 in a{$4=a[$4]}1' accession_headers.txt blast.report > outfile
   ```

Comment: Actually it didn't work for all of them, it only replaced some fields and there should be a match for all of them, so maybe someone can help correct the awk command.